# What is the meaning of the following build 「信じられない事に～～ではありませんか」?

Tags: syntax, rhetorical-questions

Taken from a game of "Alice In Wonderland" as you might guess:

> 「**信じられない事に**チョッキを着た白ウサギが懐中時計を見ながら走ってゆく**ではありませんか！**」

I guess this is sort of a fairy tale language right? I fail to see how I should combine the three parts, or what is the point of the third part 「～ありませんか」, how does it alter the sentence further than the first part?

Comment: For this usage of 「～ことに、」, see: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/41113/9831

Comment: For reference, here is the original: "Alice [did not] think it so very much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say to itself, `Oh dear! Oh dear! I shall be late!' (when she thought it over afterwards, it occurred to her that she ought to have wondered at this, but at the time it all seemed quite natural); but when the Rabbit actually *took a watch out of its waistcoat-pocket*, and looked at it, and then hurried on, Alice started to her feet, for it flashed across her mind that she had never before seen a rabbit with either a waistcoat-pocket, or a watch to take out of it, [...]"

Comment: `the original` <-- でもそれ、Lewis Carroll の *Alice's Adventure in Wonderland* の原文であって、 ゲームの "Alice in Wonderland" に出てくる原文じゃないですよね・・

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first part in question, "信じられない事に” means something like "As an unbelievable thing". You can also say things like "面白いことに” (As an interesting thing...)

The "ではありませんか” is the same thing as "じゃないか” and is used in a way close to it's literally meaning "Isn't it..."

> 「信じられない事にチョッキを着た白ウサギが懐中時計を見ながら走ってゆくではありませんか！」

So my rough translation of your line would be as follows:

> "Oh my! Isn't that a white rabbit wearing a vest, running as he checks his pocket watch?"

In my translation, I've translated "信じられないことに" as "Oh my!" to fit the feeling of Alice in Wonderland.

Comment: My apologies, I don't know what troubled me so much. I think I just didn't know how to connect 信じられない事に with the rest of the sentence in english and written "ga" instead of "ka".
I'll delete this question after you see my comment if possible.

Comment: No problem. Honestly I don't think there is any reason to delete the question since someone might be confused in the same way. But it's up to you.

Comment: Actually, the OP *can't* delete the question.  It's been answered, and the OP can't withdraw the question and answer from the community.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I didn't realize that. I agree it should stay anyway (: