# What does ことに mean when combined with 幸運 (good luck)?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I saw someone write 幸運はことに, how would you translate this to English?

Comment: Related: [About the Meaning of 〜ことに〜](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/41108)

Comment: Just to make sure, it's not 幸運**な**ことに? If so, are you able to understand the phrase now?

Comment: Yes, I think it's likely は was misrecognized as な.

Answer (score 1):

The ことに is used to emphasis the na-adjective or na-adjective before it.
The 幸運 means luck/luckly and with ことに followed, the meaning  of th
is phrase can be explained as something like 'It's lucky that ...'.

Comment: 質問に "What does ことに mean when combined with 幸運 (good luck)?" "how would you translate this to English?" って書いてありますけど

Comment: I am so sorry for my poor english skill. I will edit my answer later.

Comment: Thank  u so much for reminding me of my misunderstanding.